# Canonical link on node's print version

Tags: 7, uri, meta-tags

I'm using [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) and [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) modules, and I want to have the canonical link on the print version of the nodes too, but for some reason they're only showing on the regular version.

I'm not sure if the Print module is removing it. Even if I manually add the canonical link, it shows duplicated on the regular version but not in the print version.

Any idea about what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding a canonical link via [`hook_html_head_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7.x).